# C#, display and navigate structural 3D FEM model (helix-toolkit, SharpDX?)

Tags: c#, graphics, 3d, helix-3d-toolkit, finite-element-analysis

[image: FEM example]

Hello! I am trying to implement a simple way to display the deformed shape of a beam. I found HelixToolkit that offers perfect tools, but I can't find the way to display different tiles of the same mesh with a different colour, or gradient. I found this: https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/issues/885 that is the adding of the VertColorMaterial property, but it looks like it is for SharpDX library, but I started with HelixToolkit wpf (don't understand if in HelixToolkit is also available).

I can't even find a way to do it with SharpDX: it looks that there is almost no doc in internet.

Additionaly, SharpDX stopped its developement.

So:

- do you know any example?
- do you suggest me another library, which is fast/offers the ability of navigate the model, and it is compatible/use the wpf framework?

I also would like the ability to refine and subdivide a mesh.

Any kind of advice would be useful, I am new to the world of computer 3d graphic.

Thanks

**EDIT 1:**

I followed JonasH hint applying a texture, but it apply the texture for each tile. (See image).

I can only dinstict by out materian and in materia (set in the picture as Hue and the arrow Texture).

I need to apply one color for each polygon to give to the mesh a "FEM" style. Do you know how is it possibile with HelixToolkit? [image: 3d mesh with applied texture]

Comment: _[Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_

Comment: The plot you show at the start of your question is beautiful.  Looks like it's displaying axial normal stress on the deformed shape.  How did you generate that?

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using Kitware VTK instead of HelixToolkit. It’s extremely powerful library for scientific data visualization, well documented, perfect for finite element pre and post processing. You can take a look on my app, unfortunately it has not been documented yet, but just as an example:
https://github.com/galuszkm/STAN

Comment: Thank you! Looks extremely intresting. Would be cool to join the project.

Comment: You're more than welcome! There’s a lot of work and I could really use some help.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a color per vertex you want to use. I would recommend using wpf or helixToolkit wpf since they are quite easy to use. But as far as I'm aware they do not support vertex coloring.

A workaround would be to use a texture. I would assume you want to visualize some scalar property as a color. You would first need to create your [MeshGeometry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.media3d.meshgeometry3d?view=netcore-3.1) and assign the [TextureCoordinates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.media3d.meshgeometry3d.texturecoordinates?view=netcore-3.1), simply assign the value you want to visualize to one of the texture coordinates in the 0-1 range. You would also need to create a gradient texture, either a [gradientBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/painting-with-solid-colors-and-gradients-overview) or create an image. You would then assign the brush like:

```
        var brush = new ImageBrush()
        {
            ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("gradient.png", UriKind.Relative))
        };
           
        var material = new DiffuseMaterial(brush);
        GeometryModel3D model = new GeometryModel3D(mesh, material);
```

Comment: I tried to follow your solutions, but I found some problems: I would need a 2d gradient more than a linear gradient (or, at least, a "triangle" gradient). Ok, maybe I can still make a workaround "mixing" two gradients (even if I think, the performance would not be the best).
Then, the second problem is that I need to apply a different gradient for each polygon in the mesh: is it possible? The other solution is an UV mapping, with a gradient, but I don't find any good example to see how it works on custom meshes.

Comment: @max_s The texture is mapped to the triangles using the texture-coordinates. So you should get a unique gradient for each triangle as long as the texture-coordinates are unique. That said, I have not tested this, it is just how I would approach the problem.